# On click display the given text in alert

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x  in names">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

This is a sample code, when a user clicks on Jani,Norway . The text Jani,Norway should be copied to a alert box and alert should be display on a click event. Same goes for Hege, Sweden. In jquery i used to use $(this).find(td).html() , but in angular i am not able to do the same. 
I have attached a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jspprezf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html

```
<li ng-repeat="x  in names">
    <a ng-click="alertbox(x.name, x.country)">{{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}</a>
</li>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.alertbox = function(name, country) {
    alert(name + ' ' + country);
}
```

Comment: Suppose i have to put the name in a jsn and send it to the backend ? how should i do that ?

Comment: did you look on AngularJS tutorials ? you have to define your app and  your controller before